# Keyboard Event MediaPlayPause

Tags: javascript, dom-events

It seems that we can catch the event `MediaPlayPause`

```
keyCode: 179
keyIdentifier: "MediaPlayPause"
```

This is a good news, but actually, I didn't manage to find a way to stop the initial event that do not depend of the browser, but the OS.
Did someone find a way to cheat?

**EDIT 04/2015:**

I guess that's not possible to access the OS from a browser while doing JS.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Binding on a HTML5 sound player (using soundmanager) to play/pause the music with the MediaPlayPause button.

Comment: Please provide the source code that you are using, or if it is too big to fit here a smaller equivalent example.

Comment: This kind of stuff, but I don't get why this is necessary to understand what I'm trying to reach.
`document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === '179'){
        e.preventDefault()
    }
})`

Comment: If you provide enough information and show that you have researched your question it's more easily understood and it's more likely that someone will spend time answering it.

Answer (score 1):

You should return false from your event handler, or call both e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation.

See this other question for the full details: [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)